# How to get the post_id from data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to get the `post_id` from the object data. How do I get this?

**Here is my code from my controller:**

```php
class NotificationController extends Controller
{
    /**
    * Show All Notifications
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
    */
    public function index()
    {
        $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->toUser();
        // where('data', 'like', '%"post_id": 35%')

        $notification = $user->notifications->where('type', 'App\Notifications\LikePost');

        return response()->json(['notification'=> $notification], 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: "data": {
            "post_id": 33
        }

Comment: How to get this post_id from data

Comment: What is "the object data"? Where does it come from? Please add all clarifications to the question itself, not to the comment section

Comment: @Moaiz you need to start accepting answers that people have given you so they gain their points

Answer (score 1):

You can get object values like this:

```
$post_id = $data->post_id;
```